# No existing directory when following use-operator

Tags: php, symfony

I have learned that in best case a namespace should represent the path of its file. That means if the file is into the subdirectory "models", like in this case

- vehicles

  - cars

    - models

the namespace should be: `namespace vehicles\cars\models;`

Now, I have an example from Symfony 3 that looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

I would like to understand where those namespaces are located in. "Symfony" and "Sensio" I can both find in the directory "vendor". For example if I follow the path "Symfony", I don't find "Bundle" or if I follow "Sensio", there is also no folder called "Bundle".

Is that because Symfony doesn't care about the standards or am I just not understanding how it works? I hope it's the second one.

I hope someone can explain that to me, so I can understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony has a more complex file structure the namespace Symfony corresponds to the symfony/symfony/src/Symfony folder so if you are looking for `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` just go there and then you will find `Bundle/FrameworkBundle`.

On the other hand, for most vendor bundles the namespace corresponds to the exact folder structure like for example `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route`

If you really can't find the path to a vendor bundle you can always try looking into `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` and `autoload_psr4.php`.This is where composer defines the correspondences between directories and namespaces for your project

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. Especially the both php files explain the logic.